# Drill: This query cannot be planned possibly due to either a cartesian join or an inequality join

Tags: sql, outer-join, apache-drill

```
SELECT *
FROM hc
LEFT OUTER JOIN n
ON hc.JoinHack=n.JoinHack AND (n.`col1` IS NULL OR n.`col1`=hc.`col1`);
```

I am getting the error as in the question when running the above query in Drill. It seems Drill does not like the combination of an outer join and an OR in the condition.

If I do inner join, the workaround of an equality check on a dummy column is enough to get rid of that error (`JoinHack` in my case). With outer join it is not enough.

Running the below before the query also does not help:

```
alter session set `planner.enable_nljoin_for_scalar_only` = false;
```

What is the solution or a good workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key for Drill to accept the query was separating LEFT OUTER JOIN and the condition containing OR. So do LEFT OUTER JOIN with a subquery that does an INNER JOIN with a condition containing OR or however complicated logic you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM hc
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
  hc.id,
  n.*
  FROM hc
  JOIN n
  ON hc.JoinHack=n.JoinHack 
    AND (n.`col1` IS NULL OR n.`col1`=hc.`col1`)
) m
ON hc.id=m.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM hc
LEFT OUTER JOIN n
  ON hc.JoinHack=n.JoinHack 
  AND COALESCE(n.`col1`,hc.`col1`)=hc.`col1`;
```

alternatively using `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM hc
LEFT OUTER JOIN n
  ON hc.JoinHack=n.JoinHack 
  AND n.`col1`=hc.`col1`
UNION
SELECT *
FROM hc
LEFT OUTER JOIN n
  ON hc.JoinHack=n.JoinHack 
  AND n.`col1` IS NULL;
```

Comment: COALESCE sounded very promising and elegant. Sadly, Drill throws the same error with it.

Comment: As for UNION, how do I go about a query with more conditions, i.e.: AND (n.`col2` IS NULL OR n.`col2`=hc.`col2`) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table.

```
select * from 
(
SELECT *
FROM hc
LEFT OUTER JOIN n
ON hc.JoinHack=n.JoinHack
) derivedTable
where n.`col1` IS NULL OR n.`col1`=hc.`col1`
```

This is the general idea.   The query as is will throw errors because n and hc don't exist outside the subquery.  You can sort that out on your own.

Comment: I really hoped your solution would work. Unfortunately, this is not the case. Note that with your WHERE clause at the end you may filter out rows coming from hc that would otherwise be included if we did an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

This is very tricky logic.  I think it is usually equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM hc INNER JOIN
     n
     ON hc.JoinHack = n.JoinHack AND n.`col1` IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM hc INNER JOIN
     n
     ON hc.JoinHack = n.JoinHack AND n.`col1` = hc.`col1`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM hc LEFT JOIN
     n
     ON hc.JoinHack = n.JoinHack AND n.`col1` = hc.`col1`
WHERE n.JoinHack IS NULL;
```

Comment: How would you modify it if more conditions on more columns had to be added,i.e.: AND (n.col2 IS NULL OR n.col2=hc.col2) etc.

Comment: @Tom . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually asked.  It would be rude of you to change the question when it has been answered (multiple times, no less).  If you have another question, then ask it as a new *question* with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Let me give you +1 to not appear rude, however please note, when giving an example of a problem it is normal to reduce it to something simple for the sake of clarity and as an experienced user with high reputation you know well that it is only a matter of time when more conditions need to be added to the query. Also note that Dan's answer would deal with that case better than your answer as it is.